# C# ASN.1 decoding fail

Tags: c#, asn.1

I'm trying to decode the following simple ASN.1 structure in C#:

```
BIQAAADxPD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5k
YWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+Cjx4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4
eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4
eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4
eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4
eHh4eC8+Cg==
```

If I try decoding it using OpenSSL, it works as expected:

```
> openssl asn1parse -in sample.pem
    0:d=0  hl=6 l= 241 prim: OCTET STRING      :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/>
```

However, if I attempt to parse it with C#, I only get binary output, as if it was just a plain byte array with no ASN.1 structure: executing the following code

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          var asndata = new AsnEncodedData(Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText("sample.pem")));
          Console.WriteLine(asndata.Format(true));
        }
    }
}
```

produces the following output:

```
04 84 00 00 00 f1 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 22 55 54 46 2d 38 22 20 73 74 61 6e 64 61 6c 6f 6e 65 3d 22 6e 6f 22 3f 3e 0a 3c 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78 2f 3e 0a
```

which is identical to the binary contents of the file:

```
> cat sample.pem | base64 -d | hexdump -C
00000000  04 84 00 00 00 f1 3c 3f  78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73  |......<?xml vers|
00000010  69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30  22 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69  |ion="1.0" encodi|
00000020  6e 67 3d 22 55 54 46 2d  38 22 20 73 74 61 6e 64  |ng="UTF-8" stand|
00000030  61 6c 6f 6e 65 3d 22 6e  6f 22 3f 3e 0a 3c 78 78  |alone="no"?>.<xx|
00000040  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  78 78 78 78 78 78 78 78  |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
*
000000f0  78 78 78 78 2f 3e 0a                              |xxxx/>.|
```

Is there any way to properly parse this natively using .NET, or do I have to use Bouncy Castle or some other third-party library?

My final objective in this specific use case is to get access to the XML payload using a safe approach to interpreting ASN.1 structures, as opposed to manually trimming bytes at the beginning of the array.

Comment: This is not a proper PEM file. A PEM file starts with `-----BEGIN something-----` and ends with `-----END something-----` and is a Base64 encoded DEM (i.e. binary) encoded ASN.1, not XML.

Comment: Please feel free to save it with whatever name pleases your preferences more; it won't make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: @ckuri it doesn't matter if it contains PEM headers or not. The question is different.

Comment: @BogdanStăncescu what you expect to get in result?

Comment: I expect to get a .NET-specific representation of the ASN.1 structure present in the file. More importantly, I expect to be able to programmatically access the XML payload without manually trimming bytes from the beginning of the array.

Comment: What kind of .NET-specific representation you expect? In order to properly decode ASN into something meaningful, you have to know the ASN.1 schema (via ASN.1 module). Only then the data can be automatically parsed to something useful. Also, `OCTET_STRING` is almost always a pure binary data and isn't supposed to store text value. For text, there are plenty of string types, like IA5String, UTF8String, BMPString, etc. You should clarify your requirements.

Comment: Bouncy Castle does produce a valid structure:

var rootObj = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText("sample.pem")));

Comment: and what it produces? I'm not familiar with BouncyCastle

Comment: It produces an Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Asn1OctetString object which is a valid representation of the ASN.1 structure.

Comment: `AsnEncodedData` can show a user-friendly text representation for well-known types, such as X.509 extensions and attributes. But the formatted data isn't reversible back to ASN binary data. .NET doesn't provide any custom ASN.1 parser. You have to use 3rd party libraries or write your own. For example, I wrote my own ASN decoder in C#: https://github.com/PKISolutions/Asn1DerParser.NET and UI visualiser: https://www.pkisolutions.com/tools/asn1editor/

Comment: Hey, I didn't know the asn1editor was yours – I actually used it this week. This is part of a larger project, obviously, and I had to investigate some hairy and rather non-standard PKCS#7 structures generated by a hardware device. Thank you for the clarifications, I'd accept your previous comment as the answer.